# Adjust polygon fill transparency via ArcGIS cartographic representations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, transparency-opacity, representation

This is my first experience with ArcGIS representations (10.3.1, advanced).  I would like to adjust polygon fill transparency by editing the representation (via Layer Properties>Symbology>Representations).  Although I can modify the color pattern, symbol levels, etc. via representations, I don't see the option to change fill transparency. Here's a screen shot:

[image]

I've reviewed a 2010 ESRI pdf (cartographic-representations-tutorial.pdf), but transparency is not mentioned, so I've resorted to using the Layer Properties>Display>Transparent setting.  Shouldn't I be able to adjust transparency via representations?

Comment: Transparency isn't a symbology setting but a layer display setting (as you mentioned).  As far as I'm aware you cannot set transparency in cartographic representation.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the case.  I also tried to create the transparent representation by loading it from a .lyr file that contained the transparency.  Unfortunately the transparency did not carry through to the representation.